# Automatic Window Switcher

Tags: macos, applescript, ical, fullscreen, switching

I'm looking for a Mac app that will accomplish the following:

Switch between two full-screen mac apps - Tweetdeck and iCal, automatically on a timed interval. Back and forth without stopping.

We have a Mac setup as an office information kiosk. Staff can see quick Twitter updates, then take a look at our shared Exchange calendar in iCal.

Currently I am running an Apple Script using the keyboard shortcuts in Lion to scroll left and right between the two full screen apps. This is great, but from time-to-time the script crashes, or scrolls too far to one side. Looking for something robust and simple.

Answer (score 1):

If the applications are in different windows, I think you can simply activate them. Save this as a stay open application:

```
property counter : 0

on idle
    set counter to counter + 1
    if counter mod 2 = 0 then
        activate application "Twitter"
    else
        activate application "Firefox"
    end if

    return 3 -- in seconds
end idle
```